# How to reproduce the 3ds Max Gradient Ramp effect?

Tags: shaders, rendering, 3dsmax, effects

The material definition of a mesh is composed of these three components: *Self-Illumunation*, *Refletcion* and *Refraction*. Each of these components has a **Gradient Ramp** as a map and the mapping mode is set to spherical environment. 
I'm searching for a way to reproduce these effects in a shader (the shader language doesn't matter). Is it possible?

My first idea was to save the Gradient Ramp as a texture: you can see the result in the image below (reflection component):

[image: Reflection Gradient Ramp]

and using them in the shader through environment spherical mapping, but the result is wrong.

In this image you can see the original rendering (3ds Max, reflection component):

[image]

and in this image you can see my rendering:

[image]

The underlying idea seems to be correct, in fact there's a correlation between the two images but something goes wrong.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to do? Does your gradient ramp map control reflectivity, or provide an environment to be reflected? What kind of material are you using in 3ds max?

Comment: Could you try to create this texture with smaller light part and more of black border? Doesn't it resolve your problem?